# QML topmargin works only half

Tags: qt, qml, margin

I am trying to move rectangles in an enclosing rectangle using topmargin.

The outer rectangle has a height of 80, the inner rectangles too.

If i set the topmargin to 0, the rectangles are displayed completely.

[image]

If I set the topmargin to 80, I would have thought that the rectangles would be moved completely. However, they are still displayed halfway.

[image]

only when I set the topMargin to double, i.e. 160, are the rectangles completely shifted?

Footer.qml

```
Rectangle { id: footer; color: "lightgrey"
    property string p_buttonColor: "grey"
    property int p_buttonHeight: 80 
    property int p_buttonWidth: 80
    height: 80
    width: 80           
    Layout.preferredHeight: height
    Layout.preferredWidth: width
    RowLayout{ anchors.centerIn: parent 
        FooterButton{ p_identity: "FB1"; height: p_buttonHeight; width: p_buttonWidth; color: p_buttonColor }
        FooterButton{ p_identity: "FB2"; height: p_buttonHeight; width: p_buttonWidth; color: p_buttonColor }
        FooterButton{ p_identity: "FB3"; height: p_buttonHeight; width: p_buttonWidth; color: p_buttonColor }
        FooterButton{ p_identity: "FB4"; height: p_buttonHeight; width: p_buttonWidth; color: p_buttonColor }
        FooterButton{ p_identity: "FB5"; height: p_buttonHeight; width: p_buttonWidth; color: p_buttonColor }
    }
}
```

FooterButton.qml

```
Rectangle {
    id: button
    height: 80
    property string p_identity
    property string p_icon
    property string p_source
    Layout.preferredHeight: height
    Layout.preferredWidth: width
    radius: 10
    Layout.topMargin: 80
    Image { anchors.centerIn: parent; sourceSize.height: button.height * 0.7; source: p_source }
}
```

Comment: Your code is not runnable, we don't know what `m_config` is

Comment: Sorry the code comes from a running application, m_config is a context variable. I have adjusted the code

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: BTW you can share [QML code online](https://rb.gy/ilhtv8)